# Get html into a massive array

Tags: php, jquery, xml, dom

I have a little project where i have to save an entire website's DOM, then do some operations, such as get the css computed style etc.. (this will be done with jquery)

At the moment i have, written a couple of functions to get the HTML markup via cURL. Is there any way to then save this DOM into a multidimensional array? Recursively?

Currently im using this https://code.google.com/p/php-html2array/ (im using version 1.01) which works fine, only for some reason its missing some elements such as the main 'body' tag.. and other key elements. The url im testing is: http://www.vulytrampolines.com/

Can someone please tell me either how this can be done, or how i can edit the php using that Google code thing to see the body tag?

My code so far ([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cAZZkvrq)):

```
<?php
/**
* Website Layout Checker
*
* @package  
* @author Marais Rossouw (marais.r@vulytrampolines.com)
* @copyright Vuly
* @version 2013
* @access public
*/

require_once '../setup.php';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 6000);

class layout {

        private $_LAYOUT, $_URL, $_DOC, $_LAYOUT_ARRAY, $_SAVE_TO_JSON, $_SAVE_TO_HTML, $_HTML_BODY;

        private $_CONSOLE = array();

        public function __construct($url) {

                // Get's the contents of the page specified.
                try {
                        $client = new Zend_Http_Client;
                        $client->setUri($url);
                        $client->setConfig(array('strictredirects' => true, 'maxredirects' => 10, 'timeout' => 8));
                        $response = $client->request();

                        $this->_LAYOUT = $response->getBody();
                        $this->_URL = $url;
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $this->consoleLog($e);
                }

                // Creates a DOMDocument
                try {
                        $this->_INIT();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $this->consoleLog($e);
                }

                // Save the files
                try {
                        file_put_contents($this->_SAVE_TO_JSON, json_encode($this->_LAYOUT_ARRAY));
                        file_put_contents($this->_SAVE_TO_HTML, $this->_LAYOUT);

                        $this->consoleLog("The JSON file was saved to: " . $this->_SAVE_TO_JSON);
                        $this->consoleLog("The HTML file was saved to: " . $this->_SAVE_TO_HTML);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $this->consoleLog($e);
                }
        }

        private function _INIT() {
                $doc = new DOMDocument();

                libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

                $doc->loadHTML($this->_LAYOUT);
                $this->_DOC = new DOMXpath($doc);

                $this->consoleLog("DOMDocument created");

                $parser = new htmlParser($this->_LAYOUT);
                $this->_LAYOUT_ARRAY = $parser->toArray();


                //var_dump($this->_LAYOUT_ARRAY[0]['childNodes']);exit;

                $this->consoleLog("Dom array created");

                $this->consoleLog("There are " . count($this->_LAYOUT_ARRAY, COUNT_RECURSIVE) . " elements in the dom array");

                $this->_FILE_NAME = "VULY_LAYOUT_CHECKER-" . sha1(htmlspecialchars(trim($this->_URL)) . date("Ymd") . rand(99, 9999));
                $this->_FILE_PATH = "layout_checker\\"/*sys_get_temp_dir() . "\\"*/;

                $this->_SAVE_TO_JSON = $this->_FILE_PATH . $this->_FILE_NAME . ".txt";
                $this->_SAVE_TO_HTML = $this->_FILE_PATH . $this->_FILE_NAME . ".html";


                libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
        }

        public function toString() {
                return $this->_LAYOUT;
        }

        public function getBody() {
                $this->recurse($this->_LAYOUT_ARRAY);
                return $this->_HTML_BODY;
        }

        private function recurse($file) {
                if ($this->_HTML_BODY != false) { return; }

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++) {
                        if ($file[$i]['childNodes']) {
                                if ($file[$i]['tag'] == "body") {
                                        $this->_HTML_BODY = $file[$i]['innerHTML'];
                                        return;
                                } else {
                                        $this->recurse($file[$i]['childNodes']);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        public function getJSON_FILE() {
                return file_get_contents($this->_SAVE_TO_JSON);
        }

        public function get_SAVE_TO_HTML() {
                return $this->_SAVE_TO_HTML;
        }


        public function consoleLog($string) {
                $this->_CONSOLE[] = $string;
        }

        public function renderConsole() {
                $return = "";

                $_PAD_SIZE = strlen(count($this->_CONSOLE)) + 2;

                foreach ($this->_CONSOLE as $key => $value) {
                        $return .= str_pad($key . ":", $_PAD_SIZE) . $value . "\n";
                }
                return $return;
        }

}

class htmlParser {

        //your very own separator
        //do not enter characters such as < or >
        private $separator = '~';
        //the tags that don't have any innerHTML in them
        //feel free to add some if I missed any
        private $singleTags = 'meta|img|hr|br|link|!--|!DOCTYPE|input';

        //-- Don't edit below this --

        private $html,$level;
        public $levelArray;

        function __construct($html='') {
                $this->html=$this->removeWhiteSpace($html);
                $this->level=-1;
                $this->levelArray=array();
        }
        function __destruct() {
                //nothing yet;
        }
        private function getElement($value) {
                $ar = explode($this->separator,$value);
                $ar = explode('-',$ar[1]);
                return $this->levelArray[$ar[0]][$ar[1]];
        }
        private function parseToHTML($str,$level) {
                $ar=$this->getArrayOfReplacements($str);
                foreach ($ar as $item) {
                        $elem = $this->getElement($item);
                        $str=str_replace($item,($level==0?$elem['htmlText']:'<'.$elem['tag'].$elem['attr'].'>'.$elem['htmlText'].'</'.$elem['tag'].'>'),$str);
                }
                return $str;
        }
        private function replaceSingleTags() {
                //tags like img, input etc
                $result=preg_match_all('/<('.$this->singleTags.')(.[^><]*)?>/is', $this->html, $m);
                if ($result>0) {
                        foreach ($m[0] as $id => $value) {
                                $this->html = str_replace($value,'',$this->html);
                        }
                }
        }
        private function replaceSimpleTags() {
                //tags that only have text in them (no other content)
                $result=preg_match_all('/<(.[^\s]*)(.[^><]*)?>(.[^<]*)?<\/\1>/is', $this->html, $m);
                if ($result>0) {
                        $this->level++;
                        $oneLevel=array();
                        foreach ($m[0] as $id => $value) {
                                if ($this->level==0) $htmlText=$value;
                                else $htmlText=$this->parseToHTML($m[3][$id],$this->level-1);

                                $oneLevel []= array('str' => $value, 'rep' => $this->separator.$this->level.'-'.$id.$this->separator, 'tag' => $m[1][$id], 'level' => $this->level, 'text' => $m[3][$id], 'attr' => $m[2][$id] , 'htmlText' => $htmlText);

                                $this->html = str_replace($value,$this->separator.$this->level.'-'.$id.$this->separator,$this->html);
                        }
                        $this->levelArray [$this->level] = $oneLevel;
                }
        }
        private function replaceRemainingTags() {
                //tags that remain after everything
                $result=preg_match_all('/<(.[^\s]*)(.[^><]*)?>(.*)?<\/\1>/is', $this->html, $m);
                if ($result>0) {
                        $this->level++;
                        $oneLevel=array();
                        foreach ($m[0] as $id => $value) {
                                if ($this->level==0) $htmlText=$m[3][$id];
                                else $htmlText=$this->parseToHTML($m[3][$id],$this->level-1);

                                $oneLevel []= array('str' => $value, 'rep' => $this->separator.$this->level.'-'.$id.$this->separator, 'tag' => $m[1][$id], 'level' => $this->level, 'text' => $m[3][$id], 'attr' => $m[2][$id] , 'htmlText' => $htmlText);

                                $this->html = str_replace($value,$this->separator.$this->level.'-'.$id.$this->separator,$this->html);
                        }
                        $this->levelArray [$this->level] = $oneLevel;
                }
        }
        private function existSimpleTags() {
                $result=preg_match('/<(.[^\s]*)(.[^><]*)?>(.[^<]*)?<\/\1>/is', $this->html);
                return $result>0;
        }
        private function existSingleTags() {
                $result=preg_match('/<('.$this->singleTags.')(.[^><]*)?>/is', $this->html);
                return $result>0;
        }
        private function removeWhiteSpace ($string) {
                $string = str_replace(array("\n","\r",'&nbsp;',"\t"),'',$string);
                return preg_replace('|  +|', ' ', $string);
        }
        public function toArray($html='') {

                //first part: coding
                if ($html!='') {
                        $this->html = $this->removeWhiteSpace($html);
                }
                while ($this->existSimpleTags() || $this->existSingleTags()) {
                        $this->replaceSingleTags();
                        $this->replaceSimpleTags();
                }
                $this->replaceRemainingTags();

                //now decoding
                $ar=$this->getArray($this->html);

                return $ar;
        }
        private function getArrayOfReplacements($str) {
                $final=array();
                $ar=explode($this->separator,$str);
                for ($i=0;$i<(count($ar)-1)/2;$i++) {
                        $final []= $this->separator.$ar[$i*2+1].$this->separator;
                }
                return $final;
        }
        private function startsWithText($str) {
                $first=substr(trim(str_replace(array("\n","\r"),'',$str)),0,1);
                if ($first=='<' || $first=='>') return false;
                return true;
        }
        private function strInArray($array,$str) {
                foreach ($array as $item) {
                        if (strpos($str,$item)!==false)
                                return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
        private function getArray($html, $father='') {
                $final=array();
                if (strpos($html,$this->separator)!==false) {
                        $r=$this->getArrayOfReplacements($html);
                        foreach ($r as $i) {

                                $ar = explode($this->separator,$i);
                                $ar = explode('-',$ar[1]);
                                $elem = $this->levelArray[$ar[0]][$ar[1]];
                                $this->levelArray[$ar[0]][$ar[1]]['father'] = $father;

                                $final []= array( 'tag' => $elem['tag'], 'innerHTML' => $elem['htmlText'], 'repl' => $elem['rep'],'stratr' => $elem['attr'], 'level' => $elem['level'], 'father' => $father, 'childNodes' => $this->getArray($elem['text'],$i));
                        }
                }
                return $final;
        }
        public function loadNode($rep) {
                $elem = $this->getElement($rep);
                return array( 'tag' => $elem['tag'], 'innerHTML' => $elem['htmlText'], 'repl' => $elem['rep'],'stratr' => $elem['attr'], 'level' => $elem['level'], 'father' => $elem['father']);
        }
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['layout'])) {
        $layout = new layout($_REQUEST['layout']);
        $console = $layout->renderConsole();
        $json_file = $layout->getJSON_FILE();
        $toString = $layout->toString();
        $getBody = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/etramp/scripts/" . $layout->get_SAVE_TO_HTML();
} else {
        $console = "";
        $json_file = "";
        $toString = "";
        $getBody = "";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
        <title>Vuly Layout Checker</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html {
                height: 100%;
                margin:0;padding:0;
        }
        body {
                background: #728eaa;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #25303C 0%, #728EAA 100%);
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #25303C), color-stop(100%, #728EAA));
                font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        input, select {
                padding:10px;
        }
        select, input[type='submit'] {
                cursor:pointer;
        }
        label {
                color: #fff;
                padding-right: 10px;
        }
        form {
                margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
                width: 684px;
        }
        .text1 {
                width:49%; height:220px; resize: none; position:fixed; top:150px;
        }
        .text2 {
                width:49%; resize: none; position:fixed; top: 380px; bottom:10px; height: 58%;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var file;
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        file = <?php echo $json_file; ?>;
                recurse(file);
        });
        function recurse(file) {
                console.log(file[i].tag);
                for (var i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                        if (file[i].childNodes) {
                                if (file[i].tag == "body") {
                                        console.log($(file[i].innerHeml, $('#NEW_LAYOUT').contents()));
                                        alert(file[i].tag);
                                } else {
                                        recurse(file[i].childNodes);
                                }              
                        }
                }
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body>

        <textarea class="text1" style="left:10px;"><?php echo $console; ?></textarea>
        <textarea class="text1" style="right:10px;"><?php echo $json_file; ?></textarea>

        <form>
                <label for="layout">Website URL:</label>
                <input type="text" name="layout" id="layout" style="width: 500px" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['layout'])) ? $_REQUEST['layout'] : "http://"; ?>">
                <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <textarea class="text2" style="left:10px;"><?php echo $toString; ?></textarea>
        <iframe id="NEW_LAYOUT" class="text2" style="right:10px;" src="<?php echo $getBody; ?>"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because i have to save this as a JSON, to then read by jQuery to get the computed style for each element. Ultimately i want to make a app that will compare a website's output with previous saves.

Comment: Please contact the vendor of that library for your support options. I bet that if there is an issue there also might be a flaw - either in documentation or in the code - so that the original author should be put into the loop. Also take care that Stackoverflow is about concrete programming questions, you're merely taking us into your problem on not getting that library to work on an indivual resource without actually analyzing the code and telling us at which line of code the problem resides and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend something like phpQuery
https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

So what you would do is cURL that URL and then pass the result onto phpQuery like so:

```
phpQuery::selectDocument($doc);
```

as an example here is how to iterate though the HTML
// all LIs from last selected DOM

```
foreach(pq('li') as $li) {
        // iteration returns PLAIN dom nodes, NOT phpQuery objects
        $tagName = $li->tagName;
        $childNodes = $li->childNodes;
        // so you NEED to wrap it within phpQuery, using pq();
        pq($li)->addClass('my-second-new-class');
}
```

Comment: I dont just want the li's, i basically want everything in the dom in 1 array. Here is my code so far. http://pastebin.com/CKzSH04a (You could probably remove the ZEND stuff on the top.)